# touch utility set the relative time

Tags: linux, bash, datetime

How to do something like this:

```
touch <some random file> -10 minutes
```

I.e. change the creation or modification time relative to the currently set on file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example to :

```
 $ ls -l something
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 tgs tgs 0 2010-03-22 16:03 something
 $ touch -r something -d '-1 day' something 
 $ ls -l something 
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 tgs tgs 0 2010-03-21 16:03 something
```

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl_touch.htm

To change the mtime, add --time=mtime

Comment: This is a beautiful solution! Since osx doesn't seem to support the -d flag I ended up putting together a small shell script for it instead: https://gist.github.com/ddikman/a23d98e84c940a21193837ad0303fc1c

Comment: Thanks, I was more into Ubuntu and don't have mac access so, forgot to check on other Unix type OS.

Comment: Yeah, osx is rather unhelpful sometimes :)